# regex extract string between two characters

Tags: java, regex

I would like to extract the strings between the following characters in the given string using regex in Java:

```
/*
1) Between \" and \"   ===> 12222222222
2) Between :+ and @    ===> 12222222222
3) Between @ and >     ===> 192.168.140.1
*/

String remoteUriStr = "\"+12222222222\" <sip:+12222222222@192.168.140.1>";
String regex1 = "\"(.+?)\"";
String regex2 = ":+(.+?)@";
String regex3 = "@(.+?)>";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex1);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(remoteUri);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    title = matcher.group(1);
}
```

I am using the above given code snippet, its not able to extract the strings that I want it to. Am I doing anything wrong? Meanwhile, I am quite new to regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**`matches()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) method attempts to match the regular expression against the entire string.  If you want to match a part of the string, you want the [**`find()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method:

```
if (matcher.find())
```

You could, however, build a single regular expression to match all three parts at once:

```
String regex = "\"(.+?)\" \\<sip:\\+(.+?)@(.+?)\\>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(remoteUriStr);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    title = matcher.group(1);
    part2 = matcher.group(2);
    ip = matcher.group(3);
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/8t2EC

Answer (score 3):

If your input always looks like that and you always want the same parts from it you can put that in a single regex (with multiple capturing groups):

```
"([^"]+)" <sip:([^@]+)@([^>]+)>
```

So you can then use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\" <sip:([^@]+)@([^>]+)>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(remoteUri);
if (m.find()) {
  String s1 = m.group(1);
  String s2 = m.group(2);
  String s3 = m.group(3);
}
```

Comment: +1 Though you need `Pattern.compile` and `String` (uppercase `S`): http://ideone.com/zyNVn.  Probably a CSharpian slip :)

Comment: It resulted in pretty much your code as well. And yes, C# is a little closer to me than Java ;)